# smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0 https://support.google.2 - gsmtp', 'noreply@demo.com')

Tags: python, flask, smtp, email-verification

### **init**.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import StringField,SubmitField,PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired,Length,Email
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
import os






app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.googlemail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']=587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']=True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']=os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']=os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
mail=Mail(app)


db = SQLAlchemy(app)

logMg=LoginManager(app)
logMg.login_view='login'
logMg.login_message_category='info'

bcrypt=Bcrypt()

from portfolio import routes
```

### Routes.py

```
def send_reset_email(user):
token=user.get_reset_token()
msg=Message('Password Reset Request',sender='noreply@demo.com',recipients=[user.email])
msg.body=''' To reset your password visit the following link:
{ url_for('reset_token',token=token,_external=True) }
If you did not Make request please contact our Team
'''
mail.send(msg)

@app.route("/reset_password",methods=['GET','POST'])
def reset_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
       return redirect(url_for('admin')) 
    form=RequestResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user=User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        send_reset_email(user)
        flash('Reset Email Link Sent')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template("reset_request.html",form=form,legend='Edit Post')

@app.route("/reset_password/<token>",methods=['GET','POST'])
def reset_token():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
       return redirect(url_for('admin'))
    user=User.verify_reset_token(token)
    if user is None:
        flash('Invalid or Expired Token','warning')
        return redirect(url_for(reset_request))
    form=ResetPasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user.password=hashed_password
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Password Changed!','success')
        return redirect(url_for('Login'))
    return render_template('reset_token',form=form,legend='Reset Password Form')
```

**Keep getting this error to authenticate sender I have tried changing to my email and enabling IMAP setting but did not work**

### Returns

smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError t20sm2139075wmi.2 - gsmtp', 'noreply@demo.com')

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in **call**
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint

File "C:\Dev\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\portfolio\portfolio\routes.py", line 177, in reset_request
send_reset_email(user)

File "C:\Dev\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\portfolio\portfolio\routes.py", line 168, in send_reset_email
mail.send(msg)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
message.send(connection)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
connection.send(self)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask_mail.py", line 192, in send
message.rcpt_options)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\smtplib.py", line 867, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError t20sm2139075wmi.2 - gsmtp', 'noreply@demo.com')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prerequisite

1. you need a valid gmail account which means you need to know Email address and Password
2. you have to add those email address and password to Windows System Variable.  (EMAIL_USER and EMAIL_PASSWORD)
3. you need to turn on '
   Less secure app access' in your Gmail Account Security.
   you can google it.

Once all above prerequisite has been done, try to check that you can get those variable from command line first.

1. go to command prompt, type Echo %EMAIL_USER% and the expect return output is your email. if the %EMAIL_USER% also return then you configure step 2 above incorrectly.
2. Do not execute Python file from VS Code. This issue similar to Pycharm user as well. I think the VS Code may not be able to access OS environment somehow (possibly I do not sure how to configure that.) The alternative solution is activate your Virtual Environment via Command Line and then run Python via Command Line -- Open command prompt and go to your Python Program folder. CD Scripts and execute 'activate'

2.1 test whether your Python can get OS environment by execute Python and import os and then

```
print (os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER"))
```

The expect output is your email address.

2.2 Once it done, you go back to your main program folder and execute Python run.py

3. Try to reset password. Email should be sent. I got the email now.

> 

Seccond thing that you can try:
instead of using TLS,

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
```

Comment: i tried this. When i tried 
`print(os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER"))` 
It worked. But when i tried to run the server, it still gave the same error

Comment: Okay,it worked. Closed my cmd and again restarted it. It worked.

Comment: Same. I was getting the same error when I ran the script in VS Code and opened the `flask shell` session in the Powershell within VS Code. When I did it again in Powershell outside VS Code, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error and it solved when I ran flask script from new terminal.
Make sure to restart your terminal and IDE when you make changes to environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Turning on 'less secure apps' settings as mail domain Administrator

1. Open your Google Admin console ([admin.google.com](https://admin.google.com/)).
2. Click Security > Basic settings.
3. Under Less secure apps, select Go to settings for less secure apps.
   In the subwindow, select the Enforce access to less secure apps for all users radio button.

(You can also use the Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps, but
don't forget to turn on the less secure apps option in users' settings then!)

4. Click the Save button.

### 2. Turning on 'less secure apps' settings as mailbox user

1. Go to your ([Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/)).
2. On the left navigation panel, click Security.
3. On the bottom of the page, in the Less secure app access panel, click Turn on access.
   *If you don't see this setting, your administrator might have turned off less secure app account access* (check the instruction above).
4. Click the Save button.

Comment: With 2-step verification is the setting 'Less secure apps' not accessible. I will add a separate answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite

Check in **Control Panel\System and Security\System**->Advance Settings->Environment Variables.
Click on **New** --> Variable name -- whatever the variable you gave in your **init**.py file(EMAIL_USER),  variable value --- The email which you want to give eg: test@demo.com
Similarly for password:
Variable name -- whatever the variable you gave in your **init**.py file(EMAIL_PASS),  variable value --- The password linked to that mail (test@demo.com) eg: #$62GNMi.

- open **cmd**
- echo %EMAIL_USER%
- It should display the mail which we gave in environment variables(test@demo.com), if not close all the opened **cmd prompts** and open freshly and try.
- Similarly for the echo %EMAIL_PASS%.

**Note**:

- If you are using any IDE like sublime text, pycharm,.... make sure
  you close the virtual environment and restart the virtual environment
  if you are in windows got to your project path and use
  (env_name\Scripts\activate.bat) and restart your application.
- Also enable Less secure app access in your gmail account https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

You do it by CoreySchafer's Flask lessons, me too. So, i found desicion.

If you have Ubuntu or manjaro, you need to write your Environment Variables
not to .bash_profile file,
but to .bashrc
and then you need to reload .bashrc file by typing `. ~/.bashrc`  or `source ~/.bashrc`

If doesnt work, reboot your system. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with "VS Code Python terminal."

*In addition to the accepted answer:*

Try Switching from "Python terminal" to "CMD terminal" worked for me on VS Code!

Click on + button on VS code terminal and select CMD terminal and run your program.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOUR PROJECT IS RUNNING ON LOCALHOST**

1.

- Go to [your google account/security](https://myaccount.google.com/security), for the email you are using to
  send emails
- Navigate to **2-Step Verification** and turn it on.
- Scroll to the bottom of the and click **App passwords**
- Generate an app password that you'll use for your app to log in your google account and send an email.
- Save your password to add it to your project...

2. 

- On your terminal navigate to your root directory,  **cd**.
- Open the **.bashrc** file with your favourite text editor **vi .bashrc**
- Add this line at the top of the file add **export USER_EMAIL="your_email@gmail.com"
  export USER_PASSWORD="the app password you generated"**
- Save it and close the file. ***esc :wq***

3. 

- Go to **settings.py** on your project under the email configuration,
  replace **EMAIL_HOST_USER** value with:
  **os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL')** and the value of **EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD** with: **os.environ.get('USER_PASSWORD')**
- Navigate to your project directory and fetch the changes made in the *.bashrc file* with **source ~/.bashrc**
- Restart your Server and this should work.

*To confirm the credentials, create a simple python file **check_credential.py*** add the following then run it `import os` `my_email = os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL')` `my_password = os.environ.get('USER_PASSWORD')` `print(my_email, my_password)`

> The printed credentials should be similar to the ones in the *.bashrc file* and on your *windows environment variables*

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOUR PROJECT IS HOSTED**

1.

- Go to your google [account/security](https://myaccount.google.com/security), for the email you are using to
  send emails.
- Navigate to **2-Step Verification** and turn it on.
- Scroll to the bottom of the page and click **App passwords**
- Generate an app password that you'll use for your app to log in your
  google account and send an email.
- On your Hosting service e.g [*railway*](https://railway.app/), navigate to variables.
- Create 2 variables, **USER_EMAIL** with value equal to ***email address you are using for the project*** and variable **USER_PASSWORD** with value equal to ***app password generated***.
- *Redeploy your app and it should work*

> **Note:** *After generating the app password make sure not to use it **anywhere else** other than your app since it won't work and you'll have to generate a new one*

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yg69.png)
[enter image description here][2]

STEP1: Google Acoount Setting
STEP2: Security
STEP3: Two Step Verification
STEP4: Enable Two Step Verification
STEP5: Below in Two Step Verification
STEP6: Apps Password
STEP7: Your Application Name
STEP8: Create
STEP9: Copy Application Password
STEP10: Paste Application Password in Project.setting.py EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Paste Your Application Password'
ALL DONE✅

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need go to myaccount.google.com, Security, and allow Less secure apps.

However with 2-step verification is the setting 'Less secure apps' not accessible. Instead go to: Security, How you sign to the Google, 2-step verification, App passwords, set any name to describe your application, Create. You will obtain 16 bytes password. Use it (include the whitespace inside) as password instead of your normal gmail password (while Username is the xxx@gmail.com email address).

In some cases the settings App password setting is not visible (you are member of organization, you use special protective key,..).

Note that with 2-step verification if you use your normal gmail password and not the App password, the error message is not 5.7.0. It is: 5.7.9 Application-specific password required.