# SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/ - Django

Tags: python, django

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('USER_PASS')
```

Error:

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError h10-20020a170902680a00b0015e8d4eb1d5sm14008586plk.31 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/password-reset/
Django Version: 4.1.1
Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused
Exception Value:    
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError h10-20020a170902680a00b0015e8d4eb1d5sm14008586plk.31 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
Exception Location: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py, line 887, in sendmail
Raised during:  django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView
Python Executable:  D:\Django\Tutorial\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\Django\\Tutorial\\django_project',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'D:\\Django\\Tutorial\\env',
 'D:\\Django\\Tutorial\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 16 Sep 2022 06:10:41 +0000
```

urls.py:

```
    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path("", include('blog.urls')),
```

I am trying to set an email password reset in my Django app but get this unexpected error. What I am trying to do here is I am using Django inbuild views `PasswordResetView`, `PasswordResetDoneView`, `PasswordResetConfirmView` to reset my registered account's password through email.

Can you help me with this or provide me with some links so I can reach the core of this error?

Comment: I've had the same error while using gmail, since it said i needed 2FA. 
[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp78HO7rJMc) or [this article](https://bshoo.medium.com/how-to-send-emails-with-python-django-through-google-smtp-server-for-free-22ea6ea0fb8e) may be of help.

Comment: It seems like your google account isn't been authenticated by Django. Google doesn't support a less secure app for email. try to create an email app in google and copy the password from google and replace it with an email password in Django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue the issue was with my Gmail account you need to go to the `settings` > `security` then create a new app password and then replace the Gmail password in `settings.py` with your newly created app password.

I think your Gmail should also have `2-factor authentication`, mine was already on but if you try this I think you should first try to turn on the `2-factor authentication` and then try all these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is detailed link to solve that problem, pay attention to **system variables** set to be similar to those set on **settings.py** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61602885/smtplib-smtpsenderrefused-530-b5-7-0-authentication-required-learn-more-at)